# Replace the URL file name with new name

Tags: php, file-io

I want to replace the URL file name with new modified file name

```
$url = 'http://p1.pichost.me/i/53/1770973.jpg';
$old_file_name = basename($fullBasePath);
$new_file_name = old_file_name_modified;
$fileName = renameUrl($url, old_file_name, new_file_name);
```

I checked [rename manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) but it does not support for url. Is there some other php function for this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here? Are you trying to rename a remote file over HTTP?

Comment: i have file name in url with space `http://p1.pichost.me/i/53/1770973 name.jpg` ... while using `rawurlencode('http://p1.pichost.me/i/53/1770973 name.jpg')` , it encodes the whole thing along with `//` so I was trying to get the $filename using `basename($fullBasePath);` and the encode it using rawurlencode($fullBasePath), then rename the url file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$url = 'http://p1.pichost.me/i/53/1770973.jpg';
$old_file_name = basename($fullBasePath);
$new_file_name = old_file_name_modified;
$fileName = str_replace($old_file_name, $new_file_name, $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to de-construct the URL, then use [http_build_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php) to re-construct it.

For example:

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
$parts['path'] = urlencode($parts['path']);
$newurl = http_build_url($parts);
```